# How to mock function under the main file in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

I am trying to write an integration test for my python app and having trouble coming up with a good way to mock the logger.
Under my tests, I have the following

```
assert os.system(f"cd {TEST_PATH}; python ../../happy.py apply") == 256
```

This is working fine but I want to mock a method inside **happy.py** which is responsible to create a logger so that my tests do not log. How do I do that?

I appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by changing my main() method to receive the arguments and then using pytest's `mocker.patch` to mock the logger.